# javascript string replace SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Tags: javascript

Can someone please tell me why this doesn't work?

```
str = "program";
destdriver = str.replace(/(internal|file|program)/), "$1");
console.log(destdriver);
```

I get:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
str.replace(/(internal|file|program)/), "$1");
                                     ^
                           why that parenthesis ?
```

to

```
str.replace(/(internal|file|program)/, "$1");
```

but the whole expression looks useless : if the word is found, you replace it by itself.

Comment: Thanks. It was just a part of some sample code.